# Why is Object detection using haar classifier causing so much delay?

Tags: .net, opencv

I have around 500 positive samples and 900 negative samples for haar classification.

All of a sudden the object marker utility has started taking around 20 seconds to detect an object. Earlier it used to take only 100-200 ms to detect.
If I use earlier constructed casacde xmls they are giving perfect results. 
Only the new ones are causing a lot of delay with video as well as web cam.

What should I do ????
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

One can reduce the delay by increasing the value of scale while running the object marker utility i.e.
`objectDetect --cascade="cascade.xml" --scale=3.3 %1`

If you increase the value of scale, the detection time will decrease ....